# Fancybox 3.x.x have bug when somewhere on page div have min-height:100% property

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I just can't fix this. When one `div` on page have attribute `min-height:100%`; after click on some element with fancybox class, image shows, but page **jump in Y** for **height of childs of div** with `min-height:100%;`

Example:

```
body{height:100%;}
html{height:100%;}

some_class{
    min-height:100%;
    background-image:url();
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center center;
}

some_absolute_div_in_some_class{

     position:absolute;
     width:200px;
     height:200px;
     top:50%;
 }
```

And then I put some position:absolute div-s in `some_class` div.

Few div-s later when I build one page template, I put gallery with fancybox. And only when I remove `min-height:100% for some_class` - it works ok, with it **whole page jump on Y asis** after open fancybox.

Answer (score 1):

In fancybox.css remove "height: auto;" from:

```
.fancybox-active {
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide a link to live page/demo, I guess this is related to scrollbar hiding. You can disable that feature by setting `hideScrollbar:false`.

Comment: No, it's not related to scrollbar - page jumps because of this also but I do not talk about this. As i say, when I remove div on top of page which have min-height:100% baceuse it's have photo in background, fancybox start working ok. So for sure min-height generate this bug in fancybox 3.x.x

Comment: No, there is no bug. Your custom CSS might interfere with fancybox CSS and that it all. Since you did not provide any link to live page/demo, it is not possible to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me when some div have min-height:100% :

```
beforeLoad : function(){

    jQuery('body').removeClass('fancybox-active').removeClass('compensate-for-scrollbar');
},
```

So I need to remove classes added by plugin for body.